# re2 Regex for extracting domain

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, extract, re2

In Google Sheets, I am trying to extract domain names from URLs, which may (or may not) have `http://`, `https://`, and a subdomain (whether `www.` or something else like `mail.`). For example:

- http://www.google.com -> google.com
- mail.yahoo.com -> yahoo.com
- [www.my-site.org](http://www.my-site.org) -> my-site.org

Google Sheets uses [the re2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt) for regular expressions. The best I've been able to do so far is:
`http[s]?://www.([[:alpha:]]*.[[:alpha:]]*)`

This regular expression doesn't work for three main scenarios I've encountered:

- when the "http(s)" doesn't exist, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the subdomain (www., mail.) to also be recognized as optional
- when the domain name has a non-alphanumeric character, like a dash
- when the top-level domain has multiple levels, like .co.uk

Comment: Haha, thanks @player0 - I was afraid to click the image, but appreciate the reminder to select as answer. Your response worked like a charm, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:ftp:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)")))
```

[image]